# Повторная загрузка того же файла в форму

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть одностраничное react приложение, одна из функций которого - отрисовка некоторых графов.
Есть кнопка загрузки пользовательских данных о цвете узлов в текстовом виде.

```
<Button
      style={{ margin: 6 }}
      variant="contained" 
      color="primary"
      component="label"
    >
      Upload colors
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {this.uploadColors(e)}}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        type="file"
      />
    </Button>
```

И функция обработки, полностью не привожу, только часть связнную с чтением

```
uploadColors = (e) => {
let user_colors
if (window.FileReader) {
  let file = e.target.files[0], reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);

  reader.onload = function(r) {

    user_colors = reader.result
    //дальше что-то делаем с user_colors

}
```

}

Если пользователь загруажет файл впервые, все нормально. Далее он меняет что-то в приложении, скажем, масштаб отрисовки графа, и хочет снова загрузить тот же файл. Проблема в том, что тот же файл повторно не загружается. Как я понимаю, дело в том, что не происходит onChange, если файл тот же самый. Была мысль вручную удалять информацию об открытом файле, но я почему-то не нашел, где хранится value,от которого зависит срабатывание onChange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте вашему `input`-у `id`:

```
<input
        onChange={(e) => {this.uploadColors(e)}}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        type="file"
        id="input-field"
/>
```

Далее для очистки используйте:

```
document.getElementById("input-field").value = "";
```

Например так:

```
onChange={(e) => {
     document.getElementById("input-field").value = "";
     this.uploadColors(e)
}}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как нужно!